# Disproving a inequality implication by contradiction.

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y \in R$.
If $0 \leq y < x$ for all $x > 0$, then $y=0$.

Proof by contradiction:

Assume the opposite that is;  "If $0 \leq y < x$ for all $x > 0$, then $y\neq0$".
         Subtract $x$ from each part of the inequality to get,
                      $0-x \leq y-x < 0$
         Then multiply through by -1 to get,
                      $x \geq y+ x > 0$
Since $x>0$, this implies a contradiction of the original statement, therefore we conclude that if $0 < y < x$ for all $x > 0$, then $y=0$.
Is my reasoning correct or is there something I can improve upon?

Comment: You'd get $x>x-y>0$ not $x>y+x>0$.  That's one major mistake.

Comment: You are right. I messed up on the step where I multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: why $x > y+x>0$ contradicts that $x \neq 0$?

Comment: @Levent It would imply $y<0$ which would be a contradiction.  But there is a arithmetic mistake, it should be $x>x-y>0$ which does not yield a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's true for all $x>0$ that $0\leq y< x$ and if $y>0$ then take $x=y/2$ and you'll find a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about making a substitution.

Comment: So by letting $x=y/2$, I show a contradiction of the assumed statement, therefore the original statement must be correct? I didn't think it would be so short, lol.

Comment: Yes, the correct proof to this is very short, it's basically a one-liner.  If $x=y/2$ then it must be that $y<y/2$ which means $2y<y$ which means $y<0$ which contradicts the assumption that $y\geq0$.

Comment: I don't understand why we can let $x=y/2$ since the implication states that $0<y<x$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the contrarreciprocal $(\lnot q \Rightarrow \lnot p)$;

If $y \neq 0$ then exist $x_0$ such that $y \geq x_0$. And you can always take $x_0 = y$.

Comment: Not the most enlighening but is another proof.

Comment: Well, it is not a complete proof: the correct contrapositive is "if $\;y \not= 0\;$ then there exists $\;x_0 > 0\;$ such that $\;y \ge x_0\;$".  You did not show that your choice of $\;x_0\;$ satisfies $\;x_0 > 0\;$.  And that requires the additional assumption that $\;y \ge 0\;$.  So additionally you have to prove that original implication holds if $\;y < 0\;$ (which it trivially does).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may be helpful nonetheless: here are two direct proofs.  As in the question, all variables represent real numbers. $
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

---

The first one is inspired by [Levent](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154389/levent)'s answer, here is a simple direct proof.

$$ \calc
\langle \forall x : x > 0 : 0 \le y < x \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{logic: extract $\;0 \le y\;$ which contains no $\;x\;$ out of $\;\forall x\;$}\hint{-- note that we silently use the fact that $\;\langle \exists x :: x > 0 \rangle\;$ here}
0 \le y \;\land\; \langle \forall x : x > 0 : y < x \rangle
\op\then\hint{choose $\;x := y\;$}
0 \le y \;\land\; (y > 0 \then y < y)
\op\equiv\hint{logic: simplify, using the fact that $\;y < y \;\equiv\; \false\;$}
0 \le y \;\land\; y \le 0
\op\equiv\hint{ordering: $\;\le\;$ is antisymmetric}
y = 0
\endcalc$$

---

Using the ordering property
$$\tag 0
\langle \forall x : a < x : b < x \rangle \;\equiv\; b \le a
$$
(which is basically transitivity in disguise) the proof becomes even simpler, and proves both directions at the same time:

$$ \calc
\langle \forall x : x > 0 : 0 \le y < x \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: extract $\;0 \le y\;$ which contains no $\;x\;$ out of $\;\forall x\;$}
0 \le y \;\land\; \langle \forall x : x > 0 : y < x \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{property $\ref 0$, above, with $\;a,b := 0,y\;$}
0 \le y \;\land\; y \le 0
\op\equiv\hint{ordering: $\;\le\;$ is antisymmetric}
y = 0
\endcalc$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this. I have not studied the ordering property or what antisymmetric is but I am looking it up. I do have one question regarding Gregory's answer that does not make sense to me.
 
Why did Gregory let x=y/2? Because 0<y<y/2 is a false statement I don't see why we can do that

Comment: @user3699546 Yes, because the statement is supposed to hold *for all* $x>0$ but for $x=y/2$ it cannot hold.  Voila, contradiction.